# Why is lambda function used to define this function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am going through google's machine learning crash course and I found this piece of code, but I can't understand why 'lambda: ' is used to define this function.

```
  training_input_fn = lambda:my_input_fn(training_examples,training_targets["median_house_value"],batch_size=batch_size)
```

Why cant we just write:

```
  training_input_fn = my_input_fn(training_examples,training_targets["median_house_value"],batch_size=batch_size)
```

From what I have found out, lambda function is used to use functions without defining them explicitly and have a syntax like:

lambda x : (x*2)

This code dosen't follow the syntax either.

Link to code: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/validation.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=validation-colab&hl=en#scrollTo=Xyz6n1YHbGef

Comment: In your first example `training_input_fn ` is the function itself, in your second example it is the result of the function.

Comment: Probably whatever you pass `training_input_fn` to expects to receive a *callable* (a function) which returns the results, so this is a cheap way to do that.

Comment: Doesn't this define `training_input_fn` as a function that takes no arguments which, when called, calls `my_input_fn` as shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that with `training_input_fn = my_input_fn(...)`, `training_input_fn` now *is* your data, while with `training_input_fn = lambda: ...`, `training_input_fn` now is a function you need to call to get your data.

So, wherever you're passing `training_input_fn` to probably expects to receive a function which it will call to get the data, e.g.:

```
def foo(training_input_fn):
    the_data = training_input_fn()
```

Personally I'd prefer to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) instead of a `lambda` wrapper for this purpose:

```
from functools import partial

training_input_fn = partial(my_input_fn, training_examples, training_targets["median_house_value"], batch_size=batch_size)
```

This is now also a *callable* which will invoke your function and return its data, but it's—in my opinion—a bit more explicit what you're doing than the arguably confusing `lambda` wrapper.